# Where is an editable text file saved on computer?

Tags: memory, cpu, rom

I know that there are two main types of memory (RAM and ROM), data on ram is lost when there is power off, but on rom data is still kept but can't be removed and can only be read.

So where is a text file's data stored when I save it and turn off the laptop and edit it when I turn it on the next time?

since it's both "not lost" and "editable" (both ram and rom).

Can somebody help me with finding out about this?

there are two possible ways i'm thinking about:

1. The data is saved on rom, when I want it it's fetched by CPU, I edit it, then it is stored as a new file on RAM again (next time it's fetched again).
2. there is memory types like EPROM on which data can be erased and rewritten.

Comment: On your hard disk?

Comment: RAM is not the opposite of ROM (ROM can be RAM).

Comment: ROM is used only for firmware--very low-level instructions for interfacing with the hardware or initiating starting the computer.  RAM is used for active temporary storage.  Anything that needs to be preserved is stored on "permanent" media like a hard disk or SSD or externally on a flash drive or optical disk (or other external drive).  Tablets often use flash memory internally rather than a drive for permanent storage.

Comment: When you save you save on Hard Disk, Like you said when you run a program or edit something it is done in RAM (temporary) when you Turn off the Laptop it is gone, ROM is like what fixer1234 said for booting and low-level instructions not for running programs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprised that you know about EPROM but not about storage :-)
RAM and ROM are types of memory. Data is stored on storage devices, mainly your Hard Disk. There are several types of disks and other storage devices among which Flash ROMs are very common today and they act like re-writabe roms.

Comment: thank you. can you please name me a book in which i can read more in detail about all these things? it's ok if it's a specialized book, i'm a student i have to know about it all.

Comment: In our country there are many books in market, and I am sure there are more in yours. Meanwhile, you can take a look at this rather short article on Wikipedia and follow the links inside it if need more information:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_hardware